# Laravel database jobs on multiple servers

Tags: laravel, queue

In our probject, we queue up jobs into fixed queue names (e.g. app_data_pull, periodic_data_sync, etc.). Every server in a cluster has 1 or more thread workers (managed by supervisord) that monitor these queues, so at any time we might have 10+ artisan workers all listening to a single queue. It seems that Laravel's queue mechanism tries to synchronize and lock jobs, to prevent multiple threads from picking up the same job concurrently. But at times, I have seen concurrent execution of the same job.

Does anyone have insight in to how (or even if) the Artisan queue workers handle synchronization? Is there any particular guidance for handling signaling to ensure that jobs execute in an orderly fashion?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the **pop** and **getNextJob** methods from specific Queue class. Different queues use different methods for blocking a job. In example, DatabaseQueue marks job as reserved by calling:

```
$this->database->table($this->table)->where('id', $job->id)->update([
    'reserved_at' => $job->touch(),
    'attempts' => $job->increment(),
]);
```

Comment: From what I can see in the DatabaseQueue, a job will be marked as reserved for (by default) 60 seconds. Essentially, this locks the job for 60 seconds, but if the job takes longer than that, any other thread will see the job as available and pick it up for concurrent processing. I wonder if I can switch to Redis instead of using the database. I would like a way to prevent concurrent execution of long-running jobs, as long as their threads are alive.

Comment: My temporary workaround is to change config/queue.php->connections->database->expire to a full day (86400 seconds). This ensures that a job is locked for a full day once it is picked up for processing, but doesn't adequately address the other issues. If a thread dies, this means it will not be processed until the next day. If a job takes longer than a day, the problem remains the same. It would be great to be able to set the reservation/expire durations on the job itself.

Comment: In docs thers is explained how the timeout and retry_after works. There is an important disclaimer that says: _The --timeout value should always be at least several seconds shorter than your  retry_after configuration value. This will ensure that a worker processing a given job is always killed before the job is retried. If your --timeout option is longer than your retry_after configuration value, your jobs may be processed twice._